# Keyboard input lost when using cross-process parent/child windows

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winapi, multiprocessing

I am investigating a bug that results in key-presses being 'lost' when users are providing rapid keyboard input to our application. It seems to happen randomly. If a user writes e.g. **"I am writing this text fast on my keyboard"** the actual text that ends up in the application's text box looks something like **"Ia wrting thistext fstn mykeybrd."**

We have managed to find out that the issue seems to be related to how we integrate the text-input component into our main application. Our main app is a .NET Framework 4.8 WinForms process. The text-input component is running as a .NET 4.8 WPF app in a **separate process.** The WinForms app is responsible for launching the WPF process, passing the window handle of its own main window as an argument to the new process. Once launched, the WPF process uses the provided window handle to reparent itself as a child window of the WinForms app. This is done using Win32 API calls through P/Invoke.

```
        private void Reparent() {
            ChangeStyle(this.myHandle);
            Win32.SetParent(this.myHandle, this.hostHandle);
        }

        private static void ChangeStyle(IntPtr myHandle) {
            const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
            const uint WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;
            const uint WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
            uint style = Win32.GetWindowLong(myHandle, GWL_STYLE);
            style |= WS_CHILD;
            style &= ~WS_POPUP;
            Win32.SetWindowLong(myHandle, GWL_STYLE, style);
        }
```

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) this seems to be legal.

> For compatibility reasons, SetParent does not modify the WS_CHILD or WS_POPUP window styles of the window whose parent is being changed. Therefore, if hWndNewParent is NULL, you should also clear the WS_CHILD bit and set the WS_POPUP style after calling SetParent. Conversely, if hWndNewParent is not NULL and the window was previously a child of the desktop, you should clear the WS_POPUP style and set the WS_CHILD style before calling SetParent.

We understand that this is a bit erm... 'unorthodox', but the design has been like this for a long time without any other issues.

Interestingly, removing the code that sets the `WS_CHILD` flag fixes the lost keys problem, but causes a bunch of other issues instead.

According to [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

> Creating a cross-thread parent/child or owner/owned window relationship implicitly attaches the input queues of the threads which those windows belong to...

We interpret this like [AttachThreadInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput) is called 'under the hood', but do not fully understand what causes keypresses to be lost. Is it some sort of thread-safety issue? A race condition?

> By using the AttachThreadInput function, a thread can share its input states (such as keyboard states and the current focus window) with another thread. Keyboard and mouse events received by both threads are processed in the order they were received until the threads are detached by calling AttachThreadInput a second time and specifying FALSE for the fAttach parameter.

We have used Spy++ to monitor the Windows messages that gets sent to the WPF process and it seems that when you type slowly, WM_KEYDOWN is sent together with WM_CHAR. When the input is lost, we still receive the WM_KEYDOWN messages, but no WM_CHAR. This led us to start investigating the .NET framework source. Among other things, we found the following code in [HwndSource.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/Interop/HwndSource.cs)

```
 switch ((WindowMessage)msgdata.msg.message)
            {
            case WindowMessage.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
            case WindowMessage.WM_KEYDOWN:
                // MITIGATION: HANDLED_KEYDOWN_STILL_GENERATES_CHARS
                // In case a nested message pump is used before we return
                // from processing this message, we disable processing the
                // next WM_CHAR message because if the code pumps messages
                // it should really mark the message as handled.
                _eatCharMessages = true;
                DispatcherOperation restoreCharMessages = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatcherOperationCallback(RestoreCharMessages), null);
 
                // Force the Dispatcher to post a new message to service any
                // pending operations, so that the operation we just posted
                // is guaranteed to get dispatched after any pending WM_CHAR
                // messages are dispatched.
                Dispatcher.CriticalRequestProcessing(true);
```

The variable named `_eatCharMessages` could perhaps be related, although debugging this code using dnSpy has not made us any wiser.

We're looking for a Win32-wizard to shed some more light on this. Anything that can point us in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. We need to figure out the root cause of  the problem in order to decide how to fix it.

Comment: Note SetParent is only "legal" if you own the parent and child processes/windows, and can therefore finely tune cross processes and parenthood relations. Otherwise it's a hack that may or not work. From your post, it's not sure this is the case or not.

Comment: Have you read about the more conventional ways of hosting Wpf? Maybe something in there could provide a clue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/windows-forms-and-wpf-interoperability-input-architecture?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @SimonMourier, yes we have full control of both processes.

Comment: WPF and Winforms are themselves frameworks above Win32, masking things and just making all this more complicated and difficult to debug. Raymond Chen clearly warns you shouldn't do this. Without a reproducible code to share, it's difficult to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example